# Known Bug in PHP 7.3.x with Singleton Subclassing?

Tags: php, singleton, subclassing

With Singleton Subclassing, I get a

> Fatal error: Declaration of TheChild::getInstance(): TheChild must be compatible with TheParent::getInstance(): TheParent in ..\test.php on line 36<

Using PHP 7.4.x NTS x64 all is fine.
Using PHP 8.0.x NTS x64 all fine as well.
PHP 7.3.x NTS x64 are the bad boys.

Here is my Code:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);

class TheParent {
    private static $instance;

    private function __construct() {
        // ...
    }

    public static function getInstance(): self {
        if (self::$instance == null) {
            self::$instance = new self();
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }
}

class TheChild extends TheParent {
    private static $instance;

    private function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        // ...
    }

    public static function getInstance(): self {
        if (self::$instance == null) {
            self::$instance = new self();
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }
}
```

I am just not sure, that I am missing something here...Anybody any insights? Customer uses 7.3.x, so I am stuck with that.

Answer (score 2):

Not a bug...

PHP 7.4 introduced (full) support for *covariant return types* (also *contravariant arguments*, but that's out of the scope of your question). https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.variance.php

`self` in the parent class is not the same as `self` in the child class, that is why it is not working in PHP 7.3 (and below), but it works in 7.4 (and above) because of the aforementioned covariance (`self` of child class is a more specific version of the parent `self`).

---

This being said, there is no need to repeat the `getInstance()` method in the child class, so this is not an actual problem.

---

Also, you will probably want to read about late static binding: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php